# how to get the number of elements in an array in systemverilog?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, methods, system-verilog

I'm new to systemverilog;
I need to run over the elements of an array that I don't know its size.
I need to read 2 elements in each iteration so I cant use foreach (can I ? ).
I need to do something like that :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i+=2 ){
foo(data[i],data[i+1]);
}
```

but I don't have arraySize in hand.

Comment: Everyone that uses SystemVerilog should have a copy of the [IEEE 1800-2012 Language Reference Manual] (http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html). You could easily find your answer there.

Answer (score 5):

While using SystemVerilog, this must be one of the very first thing to learn. This is very common and important method in SystemVerilog. Either use `$size` or `arrayname.size` method.

Following is your sample code, I have used `arrayname.size` method, the same can be accomplished by `$size(arrayname)`.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < data.size ; i+=2 )
begin // no curly braces here, except constraints
     foo(data[i],data[i+1]); 
end
```

There is also a `foreach` loop for which the size of array need not to be known. The above mentioned task can be called as follows. Here you want i+1th element to exist, so you must use size method. Henceforth there is no extra benefits of this method.

```
foreach(data[i])
begin
if(i%2 == 0 && i+1<data.size)
  foo(data[i],data[i+1]);
end
```

Note that `i` is an internal variable here, no need to declare `i`.

More information can be available at [this](http://www.testbench.in/SV_10_ARRAY_METHODS.html) link. SystemVerilog LRM [1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/07/ready-for-systemverilog-2012/) must be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Is it Java? If so

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length - 1 ; i+=2 ){
    foo(data[i],data[i+1]);
}
```

If not, it would probably be same or at least similar

This `-1` in `data.length - 1` is important, because you are accessing `data[i+1]` and you have to be sure to not be out of bounds.

---

Ach sorry, I am blind, it is system-verilog... Well I put `systemverilog array size` into google and it looks like `data.size()` should work